# Different .NET 8 build results

Tags: c#, build, sdk, dotnet-httpclient, .net-8.0

I have simple application in .NET 8

```cs
await new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://ws.pharmos.cz/wssupp/SupplierWS.asmx");
Console.WriteLine("success");
```

with `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "DockerWebClientTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerWebClientTest.dll"]
```

Running the built image fails with

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
```

If I use different SDK `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-jammy AS publish` it works. What can be the difference? SslLabs didn't show any issues with server certificate.

Comment: If the exception is thrown when you _run_ the container, it probably has something to do with the certs in the OS of `final`, I wouldn't think that the `publish` intermediate image would matter in that case because you've already compiled the application and it simply copies the binaries from the intermediate image, which does not contain trusted CA's.

Comment: @gunr2171 It happens during running the image. Updated the text to avoid misunderstanding. The root CAs of final was my first guess too. But I am changing just the SDK image.

Comment: What happens if you do `docker run --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0` and then inside the shell do `apt update` `apt install curl` `curl https://ws.pharmos.cz/wssupp/SupplierWS.asmx`? Also try using the two sdk images.

Comment: Try changing the URL in your source code to `https://example.com` and build the image using both SDK intermediates. See if you get the same exception.

Comment: `example.com` or `curl` works in all images. Even running `Process.Start("/bin/bash" , "-c \"apt update && apt install curl -y && curl -v https://ws.pharmos.cz/wssupp/SupplierWS.asmx\"").WaitForExit();` works

Comment: Raised issue at SDK https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/38325